# How to read variable of a directive from a controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I downloaded an angularJS module which does multi date picker for me (composed from 1 factory and 1 directive), and I integrated them in the module that I am already building.

It works fine even after adding the directive and factory in my angular module.

How can I read the array `scope.days` created in the directive in my controller `SchedulerCtrl`?

1 factory, 1 directive and 1 controller:

**Factory**

```
schedulerApp.factory('multipleDatePickerBroadcast', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.calendarId = null;
    sharedService.message = '';

    sharedService.resetOrder = function (calendarId) {
        this.message = 'reset';
        this.calendarId = calendarId;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleMultipleDatePickerBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
}]);
```

**Directive**

```
schedulerApp.directive('multipleDatePicker', ['$log', 'multipleDatePickerBroadcast', function ($log, multipleDatePickerBroadcast) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
           ...
           days: "=",
           ...
        },

        link: function (scope) {
          // Initialization of the variable needed in the controller
          scope.days = scope.days || [];

          // Function to assign some value to scope.days
          scope.toggleDay = function (event, momentDate) {
             ...
             scope.days.push(momentDate);
             ...
          };

        },

        ...
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
schedulerApp.controller('SchedulerCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $timeout, $http, $sce) {

$scope.dbinding = [];

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<multiple-date-picker days="dbinding "/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two way binding and accessing it through attribute in template.

```
schedulerApp.directive('multipleDatePicker', ['$log', 'multipleDatePickerBroadcast', function ($log, multipleDatePickerBroadcast) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
           ...
           days: "=",
           ...
        },
```

Comment: I was reading that, but once defined in the scope of the directive, should I defined as well in the controller as $scope.days = [];? Plus how to added in the template?

Comment: Just use it from template as <template-name days="someVariable"></template-name> and it should be accessible to your scope inside someVariable, after linking.

Comment: "days" as in the variable from controller, and "someVariable" as in variable from directive?

Comment: Other ways. Days is a attribute from a directive (which you can modify in directive controller) and you use someVariable to access it inside your controller.

Comment: I've modified my post, check it out please. this way the array in the controller side never gets updated when I alter or push items to days in the directive...anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: So your suggestions was a good start, it was only missing a scope.$watch(days, function(){...}) since it doesn't update the controller automatically once the variable is edited from the directive. Therefor now it works!